# Reflections, searching strings AND ints in a class

Tags: c#, class, reflection, system.reflection

```
Class DB_Class {
  public int a { get; set; }
  public long b { get; set; }
  protected string c { get; set; }
  protected DateTime F { get; set; }
}
```

Say there is a class like above, and I want to search in that class and return an IQueryable result because maybe I want to order it later.

I need a function like below---but the below function does NOT work with "integers" or "dateTime", only strings... (because of contains function). I need a more universal function that can take any type--kinda like Python does.

Maybe I need two templates???

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, string contains)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var someValue = Expression.Constant(contains, typeof(string));
        var containsExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, method, someValue);

        return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter));

    }
```

I want to be able to call like this:

```
var table = WhereContains<typeoftable>(table, "a", "12");
   // or
   var table = WhereContains<typeoftable>(table, "c", "Jackso");
   // or
   var table = WhereContains<typeoftable>(table, "F", "11/23/201");
```

Comment: Neither integers nor dates have a `Contains` method.  What do you expect it to do with those values?  Do you just want regular equality checks?

Comment: I want to search like "11/23" and it comes up with all november 23 date results. I want to search "12" and it comes up with 1234, 1255, 5333212

Comment: So first figure out how you'd write that in SQL.  Those data types don't have a built in operator that performs that operation.  Then, after you do that, figure out how to perform that operation using an EF query that *isn't* using dynamically generated expressions, but rather that is hard coded to a specific field and all.  Once you have that, you can work on expanding it to dynamically determine the field to use.

Comment: What I am doing right now, is a big if/else statement based on the type. Then expressions using "Equal" vs "Contains" for different types. Doesn't work too well for ints and dateTimes though. I want to make it dynamic and avoid having to check types etc.

Comment: Like I said, before getting it to work dynamically you need to be able to get it working when it's not dynamic.  Next, given that you're doing completely different things based on the type, there really isn't much of any way around that.  If you have the method accept a selector as a lambda rather than a string value you can have different overloads to support different types, but that's the best you can really do.

Comment: I think Servy's solution is pretty reusable and if possible your should implement that. If you just need a quick search (for example to filter a list of items) you may first convert property value to string and then directly to your search with Contains()

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't bother, and just use big if/else statements based on every single type in my DB.

Comment: No, I don't think he's pushing for a big if/else...but code will be more prolix (unless your requirement is pretty simple, see my previous comment)

Comment: Can you replace `typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });` with your own function that you write, so it can take any data type?